# Passing object on Queue as data laravel 4 / PHP

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, queue

I created a class that is responsible to resize images once it is uploaded. This class will be used with a queue visor. Having this class in my development project the default settings of the queue is set to `sync`.

The queue work fine, but the big issue unexpected is that passing a object on the array of data, when I get it on my class handler for the queue it because an empty `array`.

This sort of `"serialization"` of the object break all my logic for implement this awesome class I made.

I would like ask if this behaviour is normal, if yes how can be a work around to pass object as data in my queue class?

This is how I pass the object on my handlerQueue class

```
$file = Input::file('file');
$image = new Image($file);
Queue::push('HandlerQueue',['image' => $image]);


class HandlerQueue
{
   public function fire($job,$data)
   {
       dd($data['image']); // Empty array :(
   }

}
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You cant pass an object onto the queue without serialization.

What you could do is pass a reference to the object, and call it again. Like this (pseudocode):

```
$file = Input::file('file');
$image = new Image($file);
$image_id = save $file and get ID  // save reference
Queue::push('HandlerQueue',['image_id' => $image_id]);


class HandlerQueue
{
   public function fire($job,$data)
   {
       $image = new Image($data['image_id']);  // use the reference and recreate the object
   }

}
```